# How to clone Doctrine 2 entity with relations?

Tags: doctrine-orm, cloning

I have an entity that has a few relations. I need to clone this entity with relations. How can I clone Doctrine 2 entity with relations?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Benjamin Eberlei answered this question before:

> You can implement __clone() and handle the copy correctly in userland.

Source: https://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/36edab6b2ac39204/1a39a8b0eaa213a8